# How to solve problems that have many distinct levels (they are recursive) in c

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I would like to know how to handle problems where there is a process which is used in many different 'levels' of a problem in c, preferable in an 'idiomatic' way.I know I did not explain this well enough, so let me give an example:

Consider the general problem of making a game solver, which is supposed to print the best next move.I think that it should check all possible moves in a `for` loop and see if it is a winning move(in this round) if it is, return the move, otherwise check every possible move the opponent can play against your move (for loop) and call the function to find the best move again.

However, I find that this approach has some limitations, such as performance (the program will spend it's time running boilerplate code required to call the functions etc)
and limited flexibility , since the function will have to find a method to communicate with the caller how good a move was found.That is, if it could be done at all.

```
bestmove()
{
  for (;i<maxmove;i++)
   {
    if(checkifwinning(moves[i])) return;
    for (;n<maxopponentmove;n++)
     {
      bestmove();
     }
   }
```

I have been messing with haskell for a while now, so I am afraid that my mind is set on seeking recursive solutions.I hope that you can show me a way to write this function in a 'c native' way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about searching a game tree to find a best move; you could use a standard algorithm like [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax).  Your approach seems to be a depth-first search of the tree which terminates at the first winning move found; note that this won't find the shortest path to a winning move nor does it guard against the opponent's winning.

There are ways to speed up the searching of game trees such as [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning).  Such a standard algorithm is the way to go - much better than worrying about the overhead of calling functions in C, etc.  C function calls are not expensive.  Beware of such "optimizations" when writing C code - the optimizer is likely to be better at such things anyway.  At the very least, first write a version in the most straightforward way so you have something to benchmark against.  Your job is to find a good algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The C language permits recursive functions. However, it has no notion of tail-recursive calls (but in some occasions, recent GCC compilers are able to optimize some tail-recursive calls into purely iterative machine code).

When coding recursive functions you should avoid too deep recursion and too big local call frames (so use heap memory).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is a [branch-and-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) like algorithm: keep a list of "open" moves (i.e., not yet considered) and a list of "closed" moves (i.e., already considered). In C this would best be implemented having two queues (open and closed). Then you would have an algorithm as follows:

```
while (open is not empty)
{
   pop gameState from open
   if (gameState in closed)
      continue;
   push gameState to closed
   for (eachMove)
   {
       computeNewState();
       addStateToOpen();
   }
}
```

There are several advantages to this compared to a recursive approach:

- you are sure that every game state is only considered once
- you do not "overwhelm" the stack

Comment: What's the meaning of "return" in this code?  It seems that the search would terminate the first time it encounters a state it has seen before.  (Perhaps "return" here means something more like C's "continue"?)

Comment: @gcbenison Sorry, I meant "continue".

Comment: And perhaps should 'push gameState...' come after 'if (gameState in closed)'... otherwise the "if" statement will always be true